# Is this moldy vinegar salvageable?

Tags: food-safety, vinegar, mold

I started making apple cider vinegar using the second method listed on http://thehealthyeatingsite.com/apple-cider-vinegar-recipe/ 
It's been little over 4 months and my mix is looking really weird. There's some white fluff on top of what looks like a vinegar mother. The more was to be expected (it's part of the reason why I went with this method, so I could get a mother for use in future batches). But the white fluff is worrying me a little bit.

Is it mold? If so, are the batch and mother salvageable?

There's also some odd, brown, tree like organism growing in the middle. That one is really throwing me off.

[image: tree/branch]
[image: tree/branch]
[image: mold on mother/scoby?]
[image: mold on mother/scoby?]
[image: mold on mother/scoby?]
<sup>(click for full size)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

> Is it mold?

It definitely is. Whatever happened to it, it is bad.

> Are the batch and mother salvageable?

I wouldn't think of that for a second. The mold is everywhere. Just get rid of it.

Comment: That is a ton of mold, at least. It shouldn't grow that well in vinegar. Looks like maybe the pH is wrong. Have you tryed pouring a bit of the liquid over baking soda? Does it even bubble?

Answer (score 2):

I'd salvage the mother, and start over with a fresh batch of water/sugar/apple.  How much sugar did you add? I have a video on making vinegar on my youtube channel, 4godliv.  And I've taught two vinegar making classes.  Before the mold gets this bad, spoon it out and spray some straight vinegar into the batch, to bring the acidity up.  And stirring it should help keep the mold growth down.